# post hoc pairwise comparison

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, model, post-hoc, paired-data

I have a model testing whether the modifications to my texts (fixed factor: Modified) affect several measures (for example IA_FIXATION_COUNT). The Texts used in my experiments are 8, and when i want to see the difference in general between original and modified texts i imput them as random factor "Text", together with the random factor "Participant". There are few additional fixed factors that also are supposed to affect measures, such as word length and the position of the word on the line.

```
glmer(IA_FIXATION_COUNT ~ Modified +
                         Word_length +
                         Position_line +
                         Page +
                         Trial +
                         (1 | Text) +
                         (1 | Participant),
                       data = paired_dataset,
                       family = poisson())
```

When I run my `glmer()`, I get that the modifications have a significant effect on my measure.

Now, if I wanted to have a look at the different texts, and specifically whether each of my 8 texts features (or not) a significant effect of Modified, I thought I could add Text as fixed factor. I have been advised, however, to run a post hoc comparison instead.

I had a look at multcomp and emmeans, but not only I have to get rid of my random variables, also the result i get is a multiple comparison among all my texts, whereas I just want to see whether Text 1 original differs from Text 1 modified and so on.

Does anyone have any recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is OK to have a model where `Text` is a random factor, used for purposes of general inferences about other factors; and another model where `Text` is a fixed factor, used for making specific comparisons involving texts. Perhaps some others disagree; I'd be interested in what they say.

To get the comparisons you want, you need to have `Text` interact with `Modified` in the fixed part of the model:

```
model2 <- glmer(IA_FIXATION_COUNT ~ Text * Modified +
                         Word_length +
                         Position_line +
                         Page +
                         Trial +
                         (1 | Participant),
                       data = paired_dataset,
                       family = poisson())
```

Then, if I understand the comparisons you want, they may be done like this:

```
library(emmeans)
emm <- emmeans(model2, ~ Modified | Text)
pairs(emm)
```

The above compares the levels of `Modified` for each `Text`. But perhaps you want a multiplicity correction for the set of all 8 of these comparisons:

```
summary(pairs(emm), by = NULL, adjust = "mvt")
```

This ignores the `by` variable (*after* the comparisons are made), and summarizes them using the multivariate *t* correction.

#### Comment

The reason you need the interaction is because with only additive effects, you are fitting a model on the assumption that the effect of `Modified` is the same for each `Test`, and vice-versa.

Which leads me to wonder if you also want them to interact in the first model as well: `...fixed part... + (1|Participant) + (1|Text:Modified)`

And in fact, carefully consider whether some other fixed factors should interact with one another...

Comment: thank you so much, this is a very useful answer! I have one doubt related to the possibility of using Text*Modified as a fixed factor: when I do, the model uses my text 1 as a baseline, and its effects are dropped in the result. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: In order to parameterize the model, the intercept confounds factor effects so we have to drop one level of each factor. So that's what you see when you look at the regression coefficients. But that doesn't mean that that level is unexplained; and that's why `emmeans()` and such are useful. You will see all 8 levels of `Test` in your `emmeans()` results!

Comment: what is the best practice when encountering the following message? ```To enable adjustments, set emm_options(lmerTest.limit = 90189) or larger,
but be warned that this may result in large computation time and memory use.```